# RSpec Request Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

Slightly at my wits end here. Been trying to find a simple version of using request_spec.rb to write some basic controller tests in RSpec to better understand them, however so many are either complex, written in the controller_spec which i've read is now deprecated or built for purely a rails app not a Rails API.

```
 RSpec.describe "Users", type: :request do
  it "request list of all users" do
    user = User.create(name: "Ben", age: 20, favourite_mums_dish: "Spaghetti")
    get("/users")
    expect(response).to be_successful
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    expect(response.body).to include("Ben")
  end
end
```

The last does not work with an

```
     Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to include("Ben")
   expected "" to include "Ben"
```

How would I create a basic test to simply test that this user has been created and the response contains it?

Thanks so much for your help in advance. Any documentation even would be helpful as I don't fully understand the Relish one either.

Comment: I don't see an issue with your test. Could you please share the code for ```UsersController#index``` and the associated index view? If the ```User.name``` attribute isn't passed to the view or isn't shown in the view, then the test may simply be correctly identifying that problem.

Comment: Are you sure your user is actually being created? Change that `create` for a `create!` and see if any exceptions are being raised.

Answer (score 1):

Ah thank you, I hadn't put the render in correctly! Thanks so much for making sure my test was correct as I am new to that test I assumed I had written that wrong, not the controller!